# Determine if a cell has scrolled off the visible area in collection view iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a collection view in which I am having a specific cell. If this cell is scrolled off from the visible area from the bottom while scrolling up, then I have to show a view. How can we achieve this?

To identify this particular cell, I have stored its indexPath. Now if we use the below check, it is valid even if the cell is scrolled past while moving downwards ie cell has scrolled off the top of the screen. But what I am looking to achieve is to find out only when the cell is scrolled off the bottom of the screen when the user is scrolling up.
`!collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.contains(specificCellIndexPath)`

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UISCrollView) {

    if !collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.contains(specificCellIndexPath) {
       // show the desired view only when specificCellIndexPath has scrolled past the bottom of the screen.
    }
}
```

Comment: this function can't help you? func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell,
                        forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }

Comment: The problem with using this delegate function is that it will be called when the cell is scrolled off from top and bottom of the screen. However, I am looking for only scrolling off from the bottom only.

Comment: You can have the top and bottom index of the page with the next and previous index of displayed you have the height of the cell and the collection view height you can count the cell that scrolled off.

Comment: you can use a combination of scrollViewDidScroll(_:) and collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:) delegate methods

Comment: for example you can understand when the last item of collection view displayed: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {  if indexpath.item == (yourList.count - 1) { print("the last index") }}

Comment: Store the last visible indexPath in your scrollViewDidScroll(_:) method as the user scrolls.

In your collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:) method, update the last visible indexPath.

Compare the stored last visible indexPath with your specific cell's indexPath to determine if the specific cell has scrolled off the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Your goal appears to be that you want to know if:

- `specificPath` cell is ***below*** the collection view frame
- `specificPath` cell is ***visible***
- `specificPath` cell is ***above*** the collection view frame

So, we'll add a class property to find the Bottom of the specificPath cell:

```
let specificPath: IndexPath = .init(item: 10, section: 0)

// we will update when the specificPath cell is visible
var specificCellBottom: CGFloat = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
```

In `scrollViewDidScroll()`, we can find out if the cell is visible... and, if not, find out if it is Above or Below the collection view frame:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    var cellPosition: Int = 1

    if collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.contains(specificPath) {

        // cell is Visible
        cellPosition = 0

        // it's visible, so we know we can get it, but safely unwrap optional
        if let c = collectionView.cellForItem(at: specificPath) {
            // this will not change after the cell has been shown,
            //  but no harm in setting it every time
            specificCellBottom = c.frame.maxY
        }

    } else {

        if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= specificCellBottom {
            cellPosition = -1
        }

    }
    
    switch cellPosition {
    case 1:
        // specificPath cell is Below the Collection View
    case 0:
        // specificPath cell is Visible
    default:
        // specificPath cell is Above the Collection View
    }
}
```

---

Here's a complete example to play with...

Simple centered label cell:

```
class CenterLabelCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let label = UILabel()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        label.backgroundColor = .yellow
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .light)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

---

Example view controller:

```
class VisibleCellCollViewVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let statusLabel = UILabel()
    
    let specificPath: IndexPath = .init(item: 10, section: 0)
    
    // we will update when the specificPath cell is visible
    var specificCellBottom: CGFloat = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 12.0
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        // we'll put the label below the collection view
        statusLabel.textAlignment = .center
        statusLabel.text = "\(specificPath) cell is Below the Collection View"
        statusLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        statusLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(statusLabel)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            statusLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            statusLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            statusLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            statusLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),

            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statusLabel.topAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])
        
        collectionView.register(CenterLabelCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "c")
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return .init(width: collectionView.frame.width * 0.5 - 8.0, height: 200.0)
    }
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! CenterLabelCell
        cell.label.text = "\(indexPath)"
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        if indexPath == specificPath {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
        var cellPosition: Int = 1

        if collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.contains(specificPath) {

            // cell is Visible
            cellPosition = 0

            // it's visible, so we know we can get it, but safely unwrap optional
            if let c = collectionView.cellForItem(at: specificPath) {
                // this will not change after the cell has been shown,
                //  but no harm in setting it every time
                specificCellBottom = c.frame.maxY
            }

        } else {

            if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= specificCellBottom {
                cellPosition = -1
            }

        }
        
        switch cellPosition {
        case 1:
            statusLabel.text = "\(specificPath) cell is Below the Collection View"
        case 0:
            statusLabel.text = "\(specificPath) cell is Visible"
        default:
            statusLabel.text = "\(specificPath) cell is Above the Collection View"
        }
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]